# How to keep data for each row in custom CursorAdapter

Tags: android

I use custom CursorAdapter and ViewHolder pattern, i  want to know how to keep data for each row.

For example, keeping favorites value (true or false)

My ViewHolder:

```
 private static class ViewHolder  {
        int column_id, column_gtext, column_isfav, column_isread;
        TextView tvText;
        ImageView btnFavorites;         
        boolean changeDefaultFav; // if btnFav clicked its change
    }
```

My newView:

```
 @Override
    public View newView(Context context, Cursor cursor, ViewGroup parent) {
        //return null;
        View view =  LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.goftar_lr_default, parent, false);
        ViewHolder holder = new ViewHolder();
        holder.tvText = (TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.goftar_text);
        holder.btnFavorites = (ImageView)view.findViewById(R.id.bg_fav);            
        holder.tvText.setTypeface(font);

        holder.column_id = cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow("_id");
        holder.column_gtext = cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow("gtext");
        holder.column_isfav = cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow("isfav");
        holder.column_isread = cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow("isread");

        holder.changeDefaultFav = false;

        holder.tvGoftarText.setText(holder.tvGoftarText.getText() + "\n" + "Append NewView");


    view.setTag(holder);
    return view;
}
```

My bindView:

```
@Override
    public void bindView(final View view, Context context, final Cursor cursor) {


        final ViewHolder holder = (ViewHolder)view.getTag();
        holder.tvText.setText(cursor.getString(holder.column_gtext));

        final int position = cursor.getPosition();

        holder.btnFavorites.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                int newValue = 1;
                if(holder.changeDefaultFav == true) {
                    holder.changeDefaultFav = false;
                    newValue = 0;
                }

                cursor.moveToPosition(position);    
                dh.openDatabase();                       
                dh.updateFavorites(cursor.getInt(holder.column_id), newValue);
                dh.close();
            }
        });
```

Please help me, thanks so much :)

Comment: "keep data" what do you mean by that? what do you need ViewHolder for?

Comment: @pskink, I want when "updateFavorites" called a boolean variable that Specific to the current row change to true or false.

Answer (score 1):

The purpose of the `ViewHolder` is to give you quick access to the subviews inside the view so you only call `findViewById()` when you create the view.

You are assigning model values (from the cursor) into your `ViewHolder` in `newView()`.  That will cause problems because when your view is recycled, `newView()` will not be called, only `bindView()`.  So you must read your cursor data within `bindView()`.

You ask, How to keep data for each row in custom CursorAdapter?  The data is already stored within the cursor, so all you have to do is move that data from the cursor into the views.  `ViewHolder` just helps you set up the view so access to things like `TextView`, etc is very fast [compared to `findViewById()`]

You should remove all your column fields from `ViewHolder` and assign cursor data values to `TextView`s etc. in `bindView()`.

Look at some more tutorials to try to understand more about how view recycling works in `ListView`.

Comment: "ViewHolder just helps you set up the view so access to things like TextView, etc is very fast [compared to findViewById()]" this is a myth, in 95% of cases view holder is useless, see: http://daniel-codes.blogspot.com/2013/11/is-findviewbyid-slow.html, btw the google's adapters dont use view holder pattern

Comment: Ummm...  https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/widget/RecyclerView.ViewHolder.html

Comment: Although I will accept that it's not a huge optimization.  I don't use the pattern a lot, and I don't notice any performance hit.  But the OP needed help understanding just what it was for, apparently.

Comment: oh come in, i mean standard Adapters (like SimpleAdapter, ArrayAdapter, CursorAdapter ets), not RecyclerView where ViewHolder is integrated with the framework, some time ago i did some measerments and for a ListView with 100 items, each item having 6 TextView, when scrolling from top to the bottom of the ListView i saved 1 ms (sic!) or so...

Comment: I in newView just use getColumnIndexOrThrow. and dont assigning model. i want when "updateFavorites" called a boolean variable that Specific to the current row change to true or false.

Comment: Hi Mehdi, I re-read your code and I see that I misunderstood.  You already have some code that opens a database, updates a record, and closes the database.  That seems like that should work, although I would expect a little different code because (for one example) you should be calling close() in a finally block, in case your update throws an exception.  But you have some code there, so it looks like you already know how to keep the data for each row.  So I don't understand your question, is your code not working? Or are you unsure if that's the right way to code it? Or something else?